# How to fix error message "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str" in python 3?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a funciton that takes a certian id number, and id type, does a query on them, and gets a specific number related to those numbers from  a database, the problem is that im working on two different databases on the same time, and the code gives me an error on one of the functions, which i demonstrated before, the full error is :

```
File "/opt/api/./WrapperMultiple.py, line 428, in ids_to_epis
epis=[int(epi) for epi in list(epis['epi'])]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

p.s: epis is initially a dataframe.

I tried almost everything, check the code multiple tiems, changed almost everything, returned to the original, everything u can imagine, i just can't seem to figure out what's the problem here, im adding the full part of the code that im trying to fix, maybe u could help me something i can't:

```
def ids_to_epis(ids, type):
     select=[]
     for id in ids:
     select = " union all ".join(select)
     query = """
     with ids as (
     {select}
     )
     select max (random) as epi from randomTable i
     join ids
     on ids.id = i.new_id and new_idtype={type}
     group by i.new_id
     """.format(select=select,type=type)
     bi_conn=SQLConnector(db='bi')
     epis=bi_conn.query_by_str(query)
     epis=[int(epi) for epi in list(epis['epi'])]
     return epis
```

Comment: Could you provide a an example of `epis` the result of the database query (at least the first rows) ?
Just as if you put a breakpoint after `epis=bi_conn.query_by_str(query)`
It's likely that epis is a tuple (not a list) therefore you can only access it by an index.
Fake example :
`epis: tuple = (1, 2)
epis[0]  # 1
epis['epi']  # TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: ["345678",
"545687"]

Comment: Please double-check that it's not ("345678", "545687").
An error occurs either if it's a list or a tuple. But it has to be a tuple for the error message to match yours.

Comment: Anyway. Either a list or a tuple it's a Sequence and it's iterable.
`epis=[int(epi) for epi in epis]` should work.

Comment: Removed the [tag:multithreading] tag from your question because nothing in it depends on your code either using multiple threads or being used by multiple threads. Somebody probably should remove the [tag:machine-learning] tag for similar reason, but I don't presume to know anything about that subject, so I won't.

Comment: The problem has been resolved,Thank you for anyone who helped. I just deleted that function and build a proper one without a pipe line. Fixed the problem.